# Did Freebase release a RDF dump recently?

Tags: rdf, jena, freebase

I recently saw on Freebase wiki that they released a RDF dump of their data. Does this data have the complete dump of their graph including metaschema? If so, is there any documentation on how to load this GB size file into a triple store such as JENA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the RDF dump is complete (or at least as complete as the quad dump was).  It includes the schema (look for `s rdf:type rdf:Class .` triples) and the metaschema (documented in ns:base.fbontology).

I'm not as familiar with Jena, but I'd be very surprised if it didn't have documentation on how to load an RDF file.

Comment: Yeah, there is documentation... use tdbloader or tdbloader2 and come on jena-users mailing list if you have problems: http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/commands.html#tdbloader ... and make sure you have enough RAM (i.e. a lot of RAM)

Answer (score 2):

See the [Jena TDB](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/index.html) documentation for how to load a large dataset into a TDB triple store

*Disclaimer* - I am a Jena developer

Comment: Thanks Rob. I shall look at it!

Comment: I got an error while loading data using TDBLoader and sent it to the jena users list. Will wait for a reply.